# Рекурсивный перебор вложенных объектов на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы, рекурсия, фракталы, перебор

Допустим, есть объект, который в качестве своих полей может содержать другие объекты, которые, в свою очередь, могут содержать другие объекты и т.д., либо содержать конечное значение любого типа, т.е., у нас есть фракталоподобный объект. Задача состоит в том, чтобы перебрать все конечные значения каждого поля исходного объекта и сделать что-то полезное.

К примеру, у нас есть объект:

```
var fractal = {
    a1: {
        b1: {
          c: 1
        },
        b2: {
          c: 222
        },
        b3: {
            c: {
                d: 33,
                e: 2.5,
                f: {
                    g: 9999,
                    h: {
                        i: {
                            j: 1001,
                            k: 'строка',
                            l: [1,2,3]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как получить все конечные значения оптимальным способом?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы перебрать все поля и узнать значения, мы могли бы посчитать вложенность полей и написать рекурсивную функцию, которая перебирала бы строго определённое количество свойств в объекте, например, что-то вроде

```
function getProp(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[prop]) === 'object') {
            console.log(obj[prop])
            for(var prop2 in obj[prop]) {
                if(typeof(obj[prop][prop2]) === 'object') {
                    console.log(obj[prop][prop2])
                    //... другие вложенные циклы for...in
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но это плохое решение, т.к. мы вынуждены дублировать код, он получается громоздким, и при этом мы не можем быть уверены, что переданный при вызове функции объект сохранит то же число вложенных полей, на которое мы и написали функцию.

Поэтому более правильно будет использовать рекурсивную функцию, которая не зависит от конкретного количества уровней вложенности свойств. Например, такую:

```
function getFiniteValue(obj) {
    getProp(obj);

    function getProp(o) {
        for(var prop in o) {
            if(typeof(o[prop]) === 'object') {
                getProp(o[prop]);
            } else {
                console.log('Finite value: ',o[prop])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var fractal = {
    a1: {
        b1: {
          c: 1
        },
        b2: {
          c: 222
        },
        b3: {
            c: {
                d: 33,
                e: 2.5,
                f: {
                    g: 9999,
                    h: {
                        i: {
                            j: 1001,
                            k: 'строка',
                            l: [1,2,3]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

getFiniteValue(fractal);

function getFiniteValue(obj) {
    getProp(obj);
     
    function getProp(o) {
        for(var prop in o) {
            if(typeof(o[prop]) === 'object') {
                getProp(o[prop]);
            } else {
                console.log('Finite value: '+o[prop])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/9e3rvp6x/)

Однако, как в комментариях заметил [Yaant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32625/yaant), существует неочевидная проблема: если одно из свойств объекта будет циклической ссылкой, т.е. будет ссылаться на одно из своих родительских свойств, то рекурсивный вызов функции окажется бесконечным, что в итоге приведёт к переполнению стека вызовов функции.

Решением проблемы может быть сохранение информации о факте перебора объекта в цикле и вывод информации о том, что объект имеет циклическую ссылку. Для этого можно добавлять обрабатываемому в цикле объекту временное свойство-флаг, а затем удалять его. Лучше выбрать максимально уникальное имя, чтобы оно случайно не совпало с уже имеющимся у объекта свойством. Например, запишем временное свойство **temp__isAlreadyHandled__** каждому объекту, который был обработан в цикле, а затем удалим это свойство:

```
function getFiniteValue(obj) {
    var handledFlag = 'temp__isAlreadyHandled__';

    getProp(obj);

    function getProp(o, stack) {
        var propertyPath;

        for(var prop in o) {
            if(typeof(o[prop]) === 'object') {
                if(!o[prop][handledFlag]) {
                    Object.defineProperty(o[prop],handledFlag, {
                        value: true,
                        writable:false,
                        configurable: true
                    });

                    if(!stack)
                        propertyPath = 'rootObject.' + prop
                    else
                        propertyPath = stack + '.' + prop;
                    getProp(o[prop], propertyPath);
                } else {
                    propertyPath = stack + '.' + prop;
                    console.error('Циклическая ссылка. Свойство: ' + propertyPath);
                }
                delete o[prop][handledFlag]
            } else {
                console.log('Finite value: ',o[prop])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var fractal = {
    a1: {
        b1: {
          c: 1
        },
        b2: {
          c: 222
        },
        b3: {
            c: {
                d: 33,
                e: 2.5,
                f: {
                    g: 9999,
                    h: {
                        i: {
                            j: 1001,
                            k: 'строка',
                            l: [1,2,3]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fractal.a1.b2.m = fractal.a1.b2;

getFiniteValue(fractal);

function getFiniteValue(obj) {
    var handledFlag = 'temp__isAlreadyHandled__';
    
    getProp(obj);
     
    function getProp(o, stack) {
        var propertyPath;

        for(var prop in o) {
            if(typeof(o[prop]) === 'object') {
                if(!o[prop][handledFlag]) {
                    Object.defineProperty(o[prop],handledFlag, {
                        value: true,
                        writable:false,
                        configurable: true
                    });

                    if(!stack)
                        propertyPath = 'rootObject.' + prop
                    else
                        propertyPath = stack + '.' + prop;
                    getProp(o[prop], propertyPath);
                } else {
                    propertyPath = stack + '.' + prop;
                    console.error('Циклическая ссылка. Свойство: ' + propertyPath);
                }
                delete o[prop][handledFlag]
            } else {
                console.log('Finite value: ',o[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/q29o8ehf/)

Более подробно в статье по [ссылке](http://romanzhivo.com/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA/)

Comment: Если в объекте есть циклические зависимости, то данный код вылетает с переполнением стека. С одной стороны, это логично, но с другой, лучше бы эту ситуацию как-то обрабатывать. :)

Comment: @Yaant, правильно понимаю, что вы имеете в виду ситуацию, когда одно из полей является переменной, ссылающейся на какой-то объект? То есть, когда есть циклические ссылки?

Comment: Да, например, если перед вызовом функции добавить что-нибудь вроде такого: `fractal.a1.b3.c.f.h.z = fractal.a1.b3.c`

Comment: @Yaant, спасибо, дописал обработку. Если вдруг знаете более лаконичное решение, буду благодарен :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function func (obj) {
     
        for(let key in obj) {
            if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                func(obj[key]);
            } else {
                console.log(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    
}
func({a: 1, b: {c: 2, d: 3, e: 4}, f: {g: 5, j: 6, k: {l: 7, m: {n: 8, o: 9}}}});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]